# Google Apps Script Timing Out (needs simpler approach)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, simplify

I'm using this script to build statistics on each of my coworkers and it includes 15 pivot tables that frequently need to have their filters updated for different time periods. I have a lot of coworkers on this sheet, so the script for 15 tables per person ends up taking way too long and times out.

I am including one table, but the code would have 15 iterations of this per person (*times 20+ people*).

How can I prevent it from timing out? Either through a work around or cleaning up my code to be more efficient.

```
function MassUpdateofFilters() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('Andrew!A1').activate();
    var sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('Batches!1:997');
    var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
    pivotTable.setValuesDisplayOrientation(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(3, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
    var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(5);
    pivotGroup.showTotals(false)
        .sortDescending()
        .sortBy(pivotTable.getPivotValues()[0], []);
    pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(4);
    pivotGroup.showTotals(false);
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setVisibleValues(['Andrew'])
        .build();
    pivotTable.addFilter(5, criteria);
    criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setVisibleValues([ '1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7'])
        .build();
    pivotTable.addFilter(16, criteria);
    criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setVisibleValues(['April'])
        .build();
    pivotTable.addFilter(15, criteria);
    criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setVisibleValues(['2019'])
        .build();
    pivotTable.addFilter(17, criteria);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Google has a guide to best practices here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

I see that you are calling the SpreadsheetApp service seven times.  This is slow.  It would be better to call it once to get the data, then call it again to write the data, (if at all possible).  Also, could you use the cache service to pull the data from the spreadsheet once, and manipulate copies of it over and over for each separate user?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend going through and the [best practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

That being said I did have to run a script across a few thousand sheets and developed this little bit of code to help with timeout issues. It runs a loop that times itself out, and you can set a trigger to run it ever 5 or 10 minutes. After a few hours, it will do the trick. Keep in mind that Google will eventually time you out if you do this too much, and you may have to wait a day or so till you can run it again.

```
function changeAll() {

  var startd = new Date();
  var diff = 0;

  var start = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("START"));
  Logger.log(start);



  for(var i = start; i < YOUR_MAX && diff < 280; i++){

    //MAKE CHANGES HERE **************************************************************************


    //END CHANGE AREA ****************************************************************************
    //Change time and counter for next run
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("START", i);

    var now = new Date();
    var difdate = (now.getTime() - startd.getTime()) * 0.001;
    diff = difdate;
    Logger.log("DIFF: " + diff);

  }

}
```